# Kik bot able to join a group

Tags: kik

I've been playing with the REST API for writing kik bots and it seems very straightforward to do powerful things.

The kik bot I'm familiar with is RAGE, and that has a feature that when talking to it you send it 'friend' command and it responds by being your friend, which makes it able to be invited into a group you're in.

My question is, what API call is being made by the bot when it receives a 'friend' command. My test bot can't be invited to a group and I'd like it to be able to.

Feels like I'm missing a bunch of logic but not sure what - anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

`Rage bot` does not use `official kik api` `Rage bot` is not a bot account from kik, It's an user account. Hence It's a self bot. There is an open source python library that allows you to turn an user account into a Bot and `Rage bot` uses that exact same api you can find the github page [here](https://github.com/tomer8007/kik-bot-api-unofficial)